# Sharepoint server publishing infrastructure not visible in Sharepoint 2010 Foundation

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am trying to activate the Sharepoint server publishing infrastructure in order to be able to use custom master pages. When I go to Sharepoint 2010 Central admin > Site Actions > Site Settings > Site Collection features, the option for Server Publishing is missing. It looks like this feature is not available on Sharepoint 2010 Foundation. Is that so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Publishing features are available in SharePoint Server 2010 (standard and enterprise), but not in SharePoint 2010 Foundation.

Answer (score 3):

You have to activate the site collection features (Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Manage Site Collection Features) before you try to activate the site feature. Once you do that, it should appear as an option.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Server Publishing features not available in SharePoint 2013 Foundation.need to deploy SharePoint Foundation 2013 Publishing Infrastructure solution in sharepoint foundation
(more details fallow this link https://spf2013publishing.codeplex.com/) after deploying need to activate SharePoint Foundation Publishing Infrastructure feature from Site Collection Features and in Manage site features in sharepoint site...

Comment: 2 things. First of all, a section called "Sharepoint" in StackExchange, would be more appropriate to post this subject. The second thing, is about your answer Vinay. This feature seems to be broken for the last cumulative updates of the SP Foundation 2013. So if you are like me, wanting to deploy this feature, please contact me, maybe from this time I will find how to workaround the deployment issue.